# Change Header background of tabItem in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, tabcontrol

How can I change Color of header in TabItem

```
tabItem1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);//This is not changing background
tabItem1.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);//This change header border color
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HeaderTemplates on the tab control and then change them in the code behind e.g:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="InvalidTabHeader">
        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ValidTabHeader">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

and then in the tab item XAML...

```
<sdk:TabItem Header="My Tab" x:Name="MyTab" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource ValidTabHeader}">
```

And then you can do this kind of stuff in the views code behind:

var invalidTabStyle = Resources[INVALID_TABITEM_HEADER_TEMPLATE] as DataTemplate;

var validTabStyle = Resources[VALID_TABITEM_HEADER_TEMPLATE] as DataTemplate;

myTabItem.HeaderTemplate = errorCnt == 0 ? validTabStyle : invalidTabStyle;

Comment: i was already following your solution and it seems what i wanted issue is that it is showing box like on that tab header area instead of all header it showing broder in middle

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately its quite common to find that even some fairly simple features require you to take on your own templating of existing controls (or as in Myles suggestion you simply overlay the default UI with your own).

The problem in this case is that the existing TabItem template assumes that the selected tab will have a white (#FFFFFFFF) background, its hardcoded into the template (as is quite common with many of the default templates).

You should note that your background value will impact the unselected tabs although rather than appearing solid your `Red` because a pink gradient.

My advice would be to bite the bullet and copy the default template for the TabItem then manipulate as you see fit.  This approach gives you more flexability without adding additional unnecessary UI elements.